# Why wasn't the fence affected by the magnetic field of the dome?

Tags: under-the-dome

In Season 2, Episode 1, the dome becomes magnetized and starts drawing objects into its walls.

[image]

As this scene plays out the metal on the characters (handcuffs, radios) and even the car are pulled into the dome. Everything is, except that fence wire.

**How come the fence on the left side of the image isn't affected by the magnetic affect of the dome?**

Comment: I haven't seen the show, but with things like this there is rarely an actual in-universe explanation given. It had already been polarised to the same polarity of the dome? It was made of a non-magnetic metal, or a non-metallic material? The wooden posts holding it down are stronger than the magnetic field?

Comment: I would normally assume it was your last one: the fence was rooted to the ground too well. However, a recent episode this season informed us that solar panels were ripped off the rooves of houses, so that doesn't seem plausible anymore either :( Still I think it's the best we've got

Comment: @MikeEdenfield The posts may be strong, but the staple holding the fencing wire in place probably isn't.

Comment: The same reasons palm trees survived alien bombardment (while everything around was turned to rubble) in the "Independence day" - its real instead of CGI.

Answer (score 3):

It could have been made of non-magnetic materials, like aluminum.